# Is it possible to set environment variables on a groovy function

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I know I can have an environment section on jenkins pipeline (declarative) for a stage.
Like this:

```
stage('Name') {
    environment {
        NAME = value
    }   
    steps {
        script {
            Do something using these env vars
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a groovy function, to define some env vars, and run something, and call it from a few pipelines.
Something like:

```
def function () {
    environment {
        NAME = value
    }
    sh "do something using these env vars"
}
```

Is it possible somehow?

(I know I can write `sh "ENV=value; some CMD"` but I have few variables, and it is less read-able).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can do this. Jenkins Pipeline stores its environment variables in a map named `ENV`. Therefore, you can add additional key value pairs to this map for additional environment variables. This would be done in Groovy syntax via:

```
// syntax option one
env.key = value
// syntax option two
env['key'] = value
```

For your example, this would look like:

```
def function () {
  env.NAME = value
  sh "do something using these env vars"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a function that can be shared by several pipelines, you need to place it to a *Shared library*.

See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

To pass environment variables to the sh:

```
withEnv(['var_name=var_value', 'var_name_2=var_value_2']) {
    echo "process to be executed with var_name=$var_name var_name_2=$var_name_2"
    sh 'bin/start'
}
```

see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables

`withEnv` you should be able to use in the files in `var` folder of your shared library.

In the classes (in the `src` folder of your library) you probably neeed to go with the `ProcessBuilder`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

```
def pb = new ProcessBuilder('script_path','arg1','arg2')
pb.environment().put('var_name','var_value')
pb.environment().put('var_name2','var_value2')
Process p = pb.start()
p.waitFor()
```