# How to split a string in Jenkins email attachment?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli, jenkins-email-ext

I want to run the script for two products product1 and product2 , the command contains string *product1 product2* and runs script for two products as expected. The command looks like below on console:

```
pytest -v  -s --browser_name "MobileChrome" --env "Production" --product_name product1 product2 --disable-pytest-warnings
```

But the problem is the result file names are `product1.xlsx` and `product2.xlsx` respectively, but as I've passed `${product_Name}.xlsx` in email attachment, Jenkins is trying to attach `product1 product2.xlsx` which doesn't exist. somehow I want to split the product name in attachment section and make it `product1.xlsx` and `product2.xlsx` so that I will get both files correctly attached in email.

[image]

[image]

in above image product name will become **product1 product2** after passing below values in build with parameters:

[image]

`$product_Name` is a string parameter and can hold multiple values:

[image]

Comment: What if you enter _Attachments:_ `referenceData/*.xlsx`?

Comment: it's attaching all .xlsx (there are more than 10) files that are there in referenceData to the mail, I want only files those are in Product_Name to be attached

Answer (score 1):

Prior to sending mails you could try:

- Project config → ***Post-build Actions*** → *<kbd>Add post-build action ▼</kbd>*: *Groovy Postbuild* → *Groovy Script* (not tested in real):

```groovy
def myProducts = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('Product_Name')

// From Editable Email Notification → Attachments' inline help:
// 'The format is a comma separated list of Ant include file syntax.'

// create a string "referenceData/product1.xlsx,referenceData/product2.xlsx"
// from myProducts here
env.filesToBeAttached = ...

// use it in Editable Email Notification → Attachments: $filesToBeAttached
```

Hopefully the environment for the following Editable Email Notification is adapted accordingly. I'm not 100 % sure about that.

A trivial alternative would be to enter at build parameter *Product_Name*: `referenceData/product1.xlsx,referenceData/product2.xlsx`.

See also:

- [*Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step (Windows)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26428580/1744774)
- [*Is it possible to set environment variables on a groovy function*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56955548/1744774)